# Loop object that in the array and in the another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, object

i have the following structure. I need to get Internal value and through in the React. I think i need to get an array of values, for example: ['Bitcoin', 'Etherium'...] and map through it. How can i implement it?

```
 let arr = [
      {
        "CoinInfo": {
                "Id": "1182",
                "Name": "BTC",
                "FullName": "Bitcoin",
                "Internal": "BTC",
                "ImageUrl": "/media/19633/btc.png",
                "Url": "/coins/btc/overview"
            }
      },
      {
         "CoinInfo": {
            "Id": "7605",
            "Name": "ETH",
            "FullName": "Ethereum",
            "Internal": "ETH",
            "ImageUrl": "/media/20646/eth_logo.png",
            "Url": "/coins/eth/overview"
      }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you'd get an array of coin names using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const arr = [{
    "CoinInfo": {
      "Id": "1182",
      "Name": "BTC",
      "FullName": "Bitcoin",
      "Internal": "BTC",
      "ImageUrl": "/media/19633/btc.png",
      "Url": "/coins/btc/overview"
    }
  },
  {
    "CoinInfo": {
      "Id": "7605",
      "Name": "ETH",
      "FullName": "Ethereum",
      "Internal": "ETH",
      "ImageUrl": "/media/20646/eth_logo.png",
      "Url": "/coins/eth/overview"
    }
  }
];

const coinNames = arr.map(x => x.CoinInfo.FullName);

console.log(coinNames);
```

Comment: Sorry @IonutAchim I thought you needed them when using strings. Will edit

Comment: @JackBashford - You need them when you need to lookup a key via a var. `const propName = 'Name'; const value = obj[propName];`

Comment: change `let` and `var` to `const` and this answer is perfect

Comment: Ah, of course @AmirPopovich That makes sense - if you used dots in that example, it would create a property literally named propName. Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: Changed as per @Pavlo requested

Comment: Object property names are always strings. You only wrap them in quotes when they are the same as reserved words or are not valid J's identifiers (e.g. contain a space, hyphen or starts with a number).

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
import React from 'react'

export default class YourComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let arr = [
            {
                "CoinInfo": {
                    "Id": "1182",
                    "Name": "BTC",
                    "FullName": "Bitcoin",
                    "Internal": "BTC",
                    "ImageUrl": "/media/19633/btc.png",
                    "Url": "/coins/btc/overview"
                }
            },
            {
                "CoinInfo": {
                    "Id": "7605",
                    "Name": "ETH",
                    "FullName": "Ethereum",
                    "Internal": "ETH",
                    "ImageUrl": "/media/20646/eth_logo.png",
                    "Url": "/coins/eth/overview"
                }
            }
        ]

        let newArr = arr.map((data) => {
            return data.CoinInfo.FullName
        })
        console.log('new array', newArr);
        return (
            <div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You’re getting downvotes because this is not how you use `map()`. `map()` creates and returns an array. Using it to loop over and push into another array is redundant. See the answers above for examples.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Thank you so much for the help! I did the mistake and later I have corrected it.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I could have done it but I thought this is the best lesson I got.